# PHP send form data more than one form/pages

Tags: php

I am a PHP beginner.

I want to send a form data to more than one form/pages.  Is it possible?

It sends data to `use.php`.  But I want that it also sends data to two more PHP files: `lock.php` and `unlock.php`.

How is it possible?

Comment: You'd either have to use client side scripting (read: "ajax") or implement it on server side in form of a router that calls those additional scripts in background. But before starting an implementation: give it a thought if that really is a good approach. It certainly is a very "exotic" thing to do...

Answer (score 0):

Make your formdata go to one script, and simply include to the other scripts and they'll have access to the $_POST variable as well.

I use this a lot myself. I have a script where everything runs through the index.php file, but functions are stored in different php files depending on what they're doing. My index.php includes all the php files I need, and inside these php files I have scripting like this:

index.php:

```
<?php
    include('pagename.php');
    include('otherpage.php');
    echo $return;  //output from previous pages
?>
```

and pagename.php:

```
<?php
    if( $_GET['page'] != 'pagename' )
    {
        return ('');
    }

    if( isset($_POST['var']) )
    {
        // some code
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Ajax on a client side. I recommend Jquery because it is very easy to start with, or you can use CURL on server side, but it is much more complicated, you can find a bunch of tutorials, just google: sending post data with curl.

Now Jquery Ajax approach:

Lets say your form has an ID of myForm:

make a selector:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("myForm").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit
    var url1 = 'your path to url1';
    var url2 = 'your path to url2';
    var url3 = 'your path to url3';

   sendAjax(data,url1);
   sendAjax(data,url2);
   sendAjax(data,url3);
//do the regular submit
$(this).submit();
});

    function sendAjax(data,url){

     $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type:'POST',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                      //here you do all the return functionality
                    },
                    cache: false
                });
            });

    }
```

What have we done here:

prevented default sending of form, 
made X ajax requests, and send the form normally.

We have made a function for simple ajax handeling just to make our code cleaner.

The problem with this method is that you must make form checking in javascript before you start sending.